# Google Maps Lat/Long Accuracy, V2-Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to write a simple application which uses Google Maps V2 API in android.
In a timer I am reading the lat long values from the googleMap mylocation function.

```
altitude = googleMap.getMyLocation().getAltitude();
latitude = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
longitude = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
```

I Plotted the lat,long using `addPolyline()` method.

The problem I am facing is while walking on road with this app in foreground, I was walking in straight line but the plot was going in nearby buildings. I have ensured that 2 lat,longs are at a distance of 10m.

I use the formula,

```
public double calcDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2,
        double lng2) {

    int r = 6371; // average radius of the earth in km
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = r * c;
    return d;
}
```

Questions 
- How to get a straight line, how to get the accurancy or margin or error so that while walking on road I dont get into buildings

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in maps and there are errors in GPS readings. Nearby big buildings will increase the errors in GPS readings due to blocked satellites and multipath from visible satellites. You might want to consider limiting your initial experiments to areas without buildings.

Concerning straight lines, if you are fortunate enough to have the map data, you could project the GPS readings to their closest points on the road.

Comment: will do that, but I didnt got answer of my question

Comment: Understanding the noise is a good start to reducing it. For example, the performance of a Kalman filter is dependent upon the quality of the specified models of noise and motion. Understanding GPS noise is difficult enough (e.g., location jumps due to changing selection of GPS satellite constellations) to understand without big buildings nearby. So your quest to understand GPS error will be easier away from them. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying solely on you location returned from a `LocationManager` of google maps location and then plotting off that you will get points that are off sometimes due to a bad GPS lock, there really isnt anything you can do about that. You are more than welcome to not use the google maps location and use the [Fused location API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) to try to get better results.

Google maps API does not provide nodes for roads so it is nearly impossible to tell how far away a point is from the road to try to straighten it out

Comment: i read somewhere I can use kalman filters to remove noise in GPS readings. How does apps like mapmyrun do it right. i had 2 phones and mine was off track many times while mapmyrun was exact on road.